# Multi-line Listview in Android

Tags: android

Hello
I have a multi choice listview. I would like to add more than one line of text to each list item. e.g.

**List Item 1**
*Subtext*

With subtext being smaller text.
etc.

I can't find a solid example of this bar making my own custom list adapter which adds complications for multi select and is sort of over my head. The way I add items currently is

```
private static final String[] items={"my", "name", "is", "mark", "i", "am", "testing", "lists"};

theList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, items);
        setListAdapter(theList);
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to have to create a custom list adapter.

<s>Start by checking out [this example](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-listview-tutorial-example/) and if you still have problems post a new question with your code that you have tried.</s>

Edit: New link. Checkout this question for an example. [Custom Adapter for List View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view)

Comment: Seems such a hassle to add a second line. I am able to create a custom listview but the checkboxes are causing me problems as I have to save the checks with the shared preferences.

Comment: I agree, it is a bit of a hassle but honestly the second you start going outside the box with layout and functionality in a ListView you are best off just creating a custom adapter. You will gain a lot more control over the ListView which IMO outweighs the cost of adding some annoying boilerplate code to your app.

Comment: @CoreySunwold link doesnt work anymore

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for a solution for multi-line ListView and came across this post.  The link above no longer works, but I found the following: http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2010/04/custom-listview-android-developer.html

The solution here worked just fine for me.  If you'e building the list dynamically, as I am, just iterate through your data to build an array of HashMaps.

~Happy coding