# Custom Adapter for List View

Tags: android, listview, android-tablelayout, custom-adapter

I want to create a `custom adapter` for my list view. Is there any article that can walk me through how to create one and also explain how it works?

Comment: This code is working just fine http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92

Comment: @Houcine That link is no longer available.

Comment: @choz : i can't find where i've mentionned the link , you can google it , you just tap "ListView with custom rows in android" and you will find lots of usefull tutorials ;)  . good luck

Answer (score 338, accepted):

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

    private int resourceLayout;
    private Context mContext;

    public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Item> items) {
        super(context, resource, items);
        this.resourceLayout = resource;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi;
            vi = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            v = vi.inflate(resourceLayout, null);
        }

        Item p = getItem(position);

        if (p != null) {
            TextView tt1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.id);
            TextView tt2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.categoryId);
            TextView tt3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.description);

            if (tt1 != null) {
                tt1.setText(p.getId());
            }

            if (tt2 != null) {
                tt2.setText(p.getCategory().getId());
            }

            if (tt3 != null) {
                tt3.setText(p.getDescription());
            }
        }

        return v;
    }

}
```

This is a class I had used for my project. You need to have a collection of your items which you want to display, in my case it's `<Item>`. You need to override `View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` method.

`R.layout.itemlistrow` defines the row of the `ListView`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:id="@+id/TableRow01"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                  android:id="@+id/id"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="id" android:textStyle="bold" 
                  android:gravity="left"
                  android:layout_weight="1" 
                  android:typeface="monospace"
                  android:height="40sp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent">

        <TextView android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
                  android:id="@+id/categoryId"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="categoryId" 
                  android:layout_weight="1" 
                  android:height="20sp" />

        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                  android:gravity="right"
                  android:id="@+id/description"
                  android:text="description" 
                  android:height="20sp" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

In the `MainActivity` define `ListView`like this,

```
ListView yourListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.itemListView);

// get data from the table by the ListAdapter
ListAdapter customAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, R.layout.itemlistrow, List<yourItem>);

yourListView .setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

Comment: Thanks for the code.. Can you explain the getView Method as in what should go into it ?

Comment: There is no need to keep the collection called items in your class, you are passing it to the super constructor. Items can be retrieved by the getItem(int pos) method.

Comment: Why hardcode the resource ID in getView when it is being passed in via the constructor? Is there a way to just retrieve the one provided at construction?

Comment: I get error in the activity here ListView yourListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.itemListView); cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: And what is my item here ListAdapter customAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, R.layout.itemlistrow, List<yourItem>); ?

Answer (score 38):

I know this has already been answered... but I wanted to give a more complete example.

In my example, the `ListActivity` that will display our custom `ListView` is called `OptionsActivity`, because in my project this `Activity` is going to display the different options my user can set to control my app.  There are two list item types, one list item type just has a `TextView` and the second list item type just has a `Button`.  You can put any widgets you like inside each list item type, but I kept this example simple.

The `getItemView()` method checks to see which list items should be type 1 or type 2.  According to my static ints I defined up top, the first 5 list items will be list item type 1, and the last 5 list items will be list item type 2.  So if you compile and run this, you will have a `ListView` that has five items that just contain a `Button`, and then five items that just contain a `TextView`.

Below is the `Activity` code, the activity xml file, and an xml file for each list item type.

OptionsActivity.java:

```
public class OptionsActivity extends ListActivity {

    private static final int LIST_ITEM_TYPE_1 = 0;
    private static final int LIST_ITEM_TYPE_2 = 1;
    private static final int LIST_ITEM_TYPE_COUNT = 2;

    private static final int LIST_ITEM_COUNT = 10;
    // The first five list items will be list item type 1 
    // and the last five will be list item type 2
    private static final int LIST_ITEM_TYPE_1_COUNT = 5;

    private MyCustomAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter();
        for (int i = 0; i < LIST_ITEM_COUNT; i++) {
          if (i < LIST_ITEM_TYPE_1_COUNT)
            mAdapter.addItem("item type 1");
          else
            mAdapter.addItem("item type 2");
        }
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    private class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private ArrayList<String> mData = new ArrayList<String>();
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public MyCustomAdapter() {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        public void addItem(final String item) {
            mData.add(item);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
          if(position < LIST_ITEM_TYPE_1_COUNT)
              return LIST_ITEM_TYPE_1;
          else
              return LIST_ITEM_TYPE_2;
        }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return LIST_ITEM_TYPE_COUNT;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mData.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String getItem(int position) {
            return mData.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder = null;
            int type = getItemViewType(position);
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                switch(type) {
                    case LIST_ITEM_TYPE_1:
                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_type1, null);
                        holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_type1_text_view);
                        break;
                    case LIST_ITEM_TYPE_2:
                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_type2, null);
                        holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_type2_button);
                        break;
                }
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.textView.setText(mData.get(position));
            return convertView;
        }

    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView textView;
    }

}
```

activity_options.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/optionsList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

list_item_type_1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_item_type1_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_type1_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text goes here" />

</LinearLayout>
```

list_item_type2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_item_type2_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/list_item_type2_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button text goes here" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub exist ordinal for Enum.. in java & kotlin

Answer (score 15):

This code is easy to understand.

**three_horizontal_text_views_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/leftTextView"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/centreTextView"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rightTextView"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**ThreeStrings.java**

```
public class ThreeStrings {
    private String left;
    private String right;
    private String centre;

    public ThreeStrings(String left, String right, String centre) {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
        this.centre = centre;
    }
}
```

**ThreeHorizontalTextViewsAdapter.java**

```
public class ThreeHorizontalTextViewsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ThreeStrings> {

private int layoutResource;

public ThreeHorizontalTextViewsAdapter(Context context, int layoutResource, List<ThreeStrings> threeStringsList) {
    super(context, layoutResource, threeStringsList);
    this.layoutResource = layoutResource;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;

    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(layoutResource, null);
    }

    ThreeStrings threeStrings = getItem(position);

    if (threeStrings != null) {
        TextView leftTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.leftTextView);
        TextView rightTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rightTextView);
        TextView centreTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.centreTextView);

        if (leftTextView != null) {
            leftTextView.setText(threeStrings.getLeft());
        }
        if (rightTextView != null) {
            rightTextView.setText(threeStrings.getRight());
        }
        if (centreTextView != null) {
            centreTextView.setText(threeStrings.getCentre());
        }
    }

    return view;
}
      }
```

**main_layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.androidapplication.ListActivity">


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        List<ThreeStrings> threeStringsList = new ArrayList<>();
        ThreeStrings threeStrings = new ThreeStrings("a", "b", "c");
        threeStringsList.add(threeStrings);        
        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        ThreeHorizontalTextViewsAdapter threeHorizontalTextViewsAdapter = new ThreeHorizontalTextViewsAdapter(this, R.layout.three_horizontal_text_views_layout, threeStringsList);
        listView.setAdapter(threeHorizontalTextViewsAdapter);
      }
   //......}
```

Comment: What is package of `ThreeHorizontalTextViewsAdapter.java`. Is it same as remaining `Activities`

Comment: ThreeStrings has no getter methods, but you refer to them in the code...

Answer (score 10):

Google has an example called EfficientAdapter, which in my opinion is the best simple example of how to implement custom adapters. http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html
@CommonsWare has written a good explanation of the patterns used in the above example
http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf

Comment: seems to be down (404), do you know where it hides by now?

Comment: @hotzen I just checked the links, and they are both still up. Perhaps there was a problem on your end?

Comment: There is no "EfficientAdapter" sample.

Answer (score 6):

[check this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html), in very simple via the `convertView`, we can get the layout of a row which will be displayed in listview (which is the `parentView`).

```
View v = convertView;

if (v == null) {

    LayoutInflater vi;
    vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.itemlistrow, null);

}
```

using the position, you can get the objects of the `List<Item>`.

```
Item p = items.get(position);
```

after that we'll have to set the desired details of the object to the identified form widgets.

```
if (p != null) {

    TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.id);
    TextView tt1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.categoryId);
    TextView tt3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.description);

    if (tt != null) {
        tt.setText(p.getId());
    }
    if (tt1 != null) {

        tt1.setText(p.getCategory().getId());
    }
    if (tt3 != null) {

        tt3.setText(p.getDescription());
    }
}
```

then it will return the constructed view which will be attached to the `parentView` (which is a `ListView`/`GridView`).

Answer (score 6):

## Data Model

```
public class DataModel {
    String name;
    String type;
    String version_number;
    String feature;

    public DataModel(String name, String type, String version_number, String feature ) {
        this.name=name;
        this.type=type;
        this.version_number=version_number;
        this.feature=feature;

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public String getVersion_number() {
        return version_number;
    }

    public String getFeature() {
        return feature;
    }    
}
```

## Array Adapter

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DataModel> implements View.OnClickListener{
    private ArrayList<DataModel> dataSet;
    Context mContext;

    // View lookup cache
    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtName;
        TextView txtType;
        TextView txtVersion;
        ImageView info;
    }

    public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<DataModel> data, Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.row_item, data);
        this.dataSet = data;
        this.mContext=context;

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        int position=(Integer) v.getTag();
        Object object= getItem(position);
        DataModel dataModel=(DataModel)object;

        switch (v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.item_info:
                Snackbar.make(v, "Release date " +dataModel.getFeature(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("No action", null).show();
                break;
        }
    }

    private int lastPosition = -1;

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get the data item for this position
        DataModel dataModel = getItem(position);
        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag

        final View result;

        if (convertView == null) {

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent, false);
            viewHolder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            viewHolder.txtType = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.type);
            viewHolder.txtVersion = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.version_number);
            viewHolder.info = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_info);

            result=convertView;

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            result=convertView;
        }

        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, (position > lastPosition) ? R.anim.up_from_bottom : R.anim.down_from_top);
        result.startAnimation(animation);
        lastPosition = position;

        viewHolder.txtName.setText(dataModel.getName());
        viewHolder.txtType.setText(dataModel.getType());
        viewHolder.txtVersion.setText(dataModel.getVersion_number());
        viewHolder.info.setOnClickListener(this);
        viewHolder.info.setTag(position);
        // Return the completed view to render on screen
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

## Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<DataModel> dataModels;
    ListView listView;
    private static CustomAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

        dataModels= new ArrayList<>();

        dataModels.add(new DataModel("Apple Pie", "Android 1.0", "1","September 23, 2008"));
        dataModels.add(new DataModel("Banana Bread", "Android 1.1", "2","February 9, 2009"));
        dataModels.add(new DataModel("Cupcake", "Android 1.5", "3","April 27, 2009"));
        dataModels.add(new DataModel("Donut","Android 1.6","4","September 15, 2009"));
        dataModels.add(new DataModel("Eclair", "Android 2.0", "5","October 26, 2009"));
        dataModels.add(new DataModel("Froyo", "Android 2.2", "8","May 20, 2010"));
        dataModels.add(new DataModel("Gingerbread", "Android 2.3", "9","December 6, 2010"));
        dataModels.add(new DataModel("Honeycomb","Android 3.0","11","February 22, 2011"));
        dataModels.add(new DataModel("Ice Cream Sandwich", "Android 4.0", "14","October 18, 2011"));
        dataModels.add(new DataModel("Jelly Bean", "Android 4.2", "16","July 9, 2012"));
        dataModels.add(new DataModel("Kitkat", "Android 4.4", "19","October 31, 2013"));
        dataModels.add(new DataModel("Lollipop","Android 5.0","21","November 12, 2014"));
        dataModels.add(new DataModel("Marshmallow", "Android 6.0", "23","October 5, 2015"));

        adapter= new CustomAdapter(dataModels,getApplicationContext());

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                DataModel dataModel= dataModels.get(position);

                Snackbar.make(view, dataModel.getName()+"\n"+dataModel.getType()+" API: "+dataModel.getVersion_number(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("No action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

## row_item.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Marshmallow"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/type"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Android 6.0"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/version_heading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="API: "
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/version_number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="23"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceButton"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can take a look at [this sample](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List4.html) in the official ApiDemos. It shows how to extend `BaseAdapter` and apply it to a `ListView`. After that, just look at the reference for `BaseAdapter` and try to understand what each method does (including the inherited ones) and when/how to use it.

Also, [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+custom+adapter+tutorial) is your friend :).

Comment: yeah google is the friend, but the problem is that the hits you end up with are to using arrayadapter etc crap. had I not known from experience that I was looking for "what was the name of the baseadapter" I would have now gone and done unnecessarely complicated arraylist adapter.

Comment: google is my friend because somebody asks questions and somebody answers. if nobody asks google cannot be my friend. so pls stop saying this.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the complete walk through to create a custom adapter for list view step by step -

https://www.caveofprogramming.com/guest-posts/custom-listview-with-imageview-and-textview-in-android.html

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{   
    String [] result;
    Context context;
 int [] imageId;
      private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public CustomAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, String[] prgmNameList, int[] prgmImages) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        result=prgmNameList;
        context=mainActivity;
        imageId=prgmImages;
         inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
                 getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return result.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public class Holder
    {
        TextView tv;
        ImageView img;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Holder holder=new Holder();
        View rowView;       
             rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.program_list, null);
             holder.tv=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
             holder.img=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);       
         holder.tv.setText(result[position]);
         holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);         
         rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked "+result[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });   
        return rowView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Belal on 9/14/2017.
 */

//we need to extend the ArrayAdapter class as we are building an adapter
public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Hero> {

    //the list values in the List of type hero 
    List<Hero> heroList;

    //activity context 
    Context context;

    //the layout resource file for the list items
    int resource;

    //constructor initializing the values 
    public MyListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Hero> heroList) {
        super(context, resource, heroList);
        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;
        this.heroList = heroList;
    }

    //this will return the ListView Item as a View
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        //we need to get the view of the xml for our list item
        //And for this we need a layoutinflater
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        //getting the view
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(resource, null, false);

        //getting the view elements of the list from the view
        ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        TextView textViewName = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        TextView textViewTeam = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewTeam);
        Button buttonDelete = view.findViewById(R.id.buttonDelete);

        //getting the hero of the specified position
        Hero hero = heroList.get(position);

        //adding values to the list item 
        imageView.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(hero.getImage()));
        textViewName.setText(hero.getName());
        textViewTeam.setText(hero.getTeam());

        //adding a click listener to the button to remove item from the list
        buttonDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //we will call this method to remove the selected value from the list
                //we are passing the position which is to be removed in the method 
                removeHero(position);
            }
        });

        //finally returning the view
        return view;
    }

    //this method will remove the item from the list 
    private void removeHero(final int position) {
        //Creating an alert dialog to confirm the deletion
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setTitle("Are you sure you want to delete this?");

        //if the response is positive in the alert 
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                //removing the item 
                heroList.remove(position);

                //reloading the list 
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        //if response is negative nothing is being done 
        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            }
        });

        //creating and displaying the alert dialog 
        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Source: **[Custom ListView Android Tutorial](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/custom-listview-android/)**

Answer (score 0):

`BaseAdapter` is best custom adapter for listview.

```
Class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{}
```

and it has many functions such as `getCount()`, `getView()` etc.

Answer (score 0):

A more compact example of a custom adapter (using list array as my data):

```
class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object> {
    public ArrayAdapter(Context context, List<MyObject> objectList) {
        super(context, R.layout.my_list_item, R.id.textViewTitle, objectList.toArray());
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        TextView title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageViewAccessory);
        MyObject obj = (MyObject) getItem(position);
        icon.setImageBitmap( ... );
        title.setText(obj.name);
        return row;
    }
}
```

And this is how to use it:

```
List<MyObject> objectList = ...
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this.getActivity(), objectList);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    ArrayList<BookPojo> data;
    Context ctx;
    int index=0;

    public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<BookPojo> data, Context ctx) {
        super();
        this.data = data;
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View v=convertview;

        if(v==null){
            LayoutInflater vi=LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
            v=vi.inflate(R.layout.messgeview,null);

        }

        RelativeLayout rlmessage=(RelativeLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.rlmessgeview);

        TextView tvisdn=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvisdn);
        TextView tvtitle=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvtitle);
        TextView tvauthor=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvauthor);
        TextView tvprice=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvprice);

        BookPojo bpj=data.get(position);

        tvisdn.setText(bpj.isdn+"");
        tvtitle.setText(bpj.title);
        tvauthor.setText(bpj.author);
        tvprice.setText(bpj.price+"");

        if(index%2==0)
        {
            rlmessage.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        }
        else
        {
            rlmessage.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);

        }

        index++;

        return v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Context;

import android.text.Html;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;

import android.view.View;

import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.BaseAdapter;

import android.widget.ImageView;

import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class OurteamAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context cont;
    ArrayList<OurteamModel> llist;
    OurteamAdapter madap;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    JsonHelper Jobj;
    String Id;
    JSONObject obj = null;
    int position = 0;
    public OurteamAdapter(Context c,ArrayList<OurteamModel> Mi)
    {
        this.cont = c;
        this.llist = Mi;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return llist.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return llist.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater in = (LayoutInflater) cont.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = in.inflate(R.layout.doctorlist, null);
        }
        TextView category = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        ImageView i1=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        category.setText(Html.fromHtml(llist.get(position).getGalleryName()));
        title.setText(Html.fromHtml(llist.get(position).getGalleryDetail()));
        if(llist.get(position).getImagesrc()!=null)
        {
            i1.setImageBitmap(llist.get(position).getImagesrc());
        }
        else
        {
            i1.setImageResource(R.drawable.anandlogo);
        }
        return convertView;
    }

}
```